# IndexOutOfBoundException while adding in queueList

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

```
private void removeQueue(Queue queue)
    {
        queue.setTodoDeleted(false);
        if ( queueIndex != -1) {
            this.queueList.add(queueIndex , queue);
            mItemManger.closeAllItems();
        }
    }
```

where queueList is ArrayList of `queue` ArrayList `queuelist`.

**Problem** : Index is 2 and list size is 1 while adding in the queueList so, `IndexOutOfBoundException` throws at Line
`this.queueList.add(queueIndex , queue)`.

What is the best way to avoid this? In Advanced, thanks

Comment: Where is `queueIndex` is coming from ? It should follow the `queue` size ...

Comment: Index is 2 and list size is 1 , You are trying to get element which doest not exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid IndexOutOfBounds issue , Check the actual size and index that you are going to use before performing the operation.

```
if ( queueList.size()>queueIndex)
{
   this.queueList.add(queueIndex , queue);
}
// Add else part if needed
```

Comment: Thanks, venkat using this it's working no exception thrown.

Comment: @Swift You should tried to find **why** queueIndex is bigger than the actual size.